# c++ - Issue in calling marco which consists of string and number

Tags: c++

I am facing an issue while trying to call a macro from main function.
my macro is string and number, only the number changes and the string remains constant.
In main function I have a variable which contains int value, how do I use this variable to call a macro.

I have a code as below.

```
#include <iostream>

#define INT_1 cout<<"int1"<<endl
#define INT_2 cout<<"int1"<<endl
#define INT_3 cout<<"int1"<<endl
#define INT_4 cout<<"int1"<<endl
#define INT_5 cout<<"int1"<<endl

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    std::string s = "INT_" + std::to_string(x);
    s; //If I print this, I will get INT_1, but this is not calling the macro.
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried other methods as well, which was unsuccessful, can anyone please suggest a way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A macro is applied before the code is compiled, it is just a search and replace. As this is done before compilation and therefor also before runtime, there is no way that it can utilize runtime variables or any other variable.

Comment: Is this some type of academic assignment to use a macro? If not aoid it.

Comment: macros are expanded at compilation time. The compiler cannot generate code for a macro which would depend on a variable value (only known a execution time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to study Macro in detail
[Ref1](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html)
[Ref2](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/)

*"A macro is a fragment of code which has been given a name. Whenever the name is used, it is replaced by the contents of the macro. "*

You are trying to create this string at run time but macro get resolve at compile time.